# If someone dies doing something risky is it suicide?

Tags: sharia, islamic-philosophy, death, suicide

Something I have always been wondering about, people tend to do a lot of risky things which may have fatal consequences and they are aware of that, but happen to do it any way.

Such acts can be driving dangerously fast or sky diving and taking part in other other extreme sports, every performer of these acts is fully aware of the consequences which may occur, for example I may be going sky diving but a parachute may not open in time eventually getting squished to land...\o/..

Now as these people are aware of the consequences but tend to perform such acts any way, would dying while  performing them count as suicide in Islam as it is not a natural death or due to sickness?

Doesn't the following verse relate to what is above:

> (2:195)And spend in the way of Allah and do not throw [yourselves] with your
>   [own] hands into destruction [by refraining]. And do good; indeed,
>   Allah loves the doers of good

Comment: You can ask in this question only that dies sudden death without reciting Kalma while doing risky work? What happens to that person?

Answer (score 4):

Surely it's not suicide. In Islam our intention and our tries are what we decide and the result is decided by Allah. So if you intend to dive and die it counts as suicide, but if you know the risk and dive for fun and adventure then it is not.

Everything has a risk but the percentage is just different; in an air plane you have safety in 99% of flights; in car driving in an European country you have 2% risk of crash; in 3rd world countries you have 30%. So even if the risk of your life is 99.99% but your intentions are to survive even with 0.01% probability it will not be counted as a suicide.

Comment: Big rule: ALLAH KNOWS AT LEAST AS MUCH AS WE KNOW. so try to be honest with yourself with your real intentions.

Comment: Ha ha.. Very nice comment. And +1 fir answer.

Answer (score 1):

Seeking "adrenaline rush" is far from killing one's self. Both are quite different in the intent (niyyat) as well as method of doing it.

The people who do the first is usually known as "adrenaline junkies", whereas the other ones are mentally broken. Those "junkies" calculate the risks and and carry least amount of safety gears, but suicidal people don't.

Also, there's a hadith mentioning that Allah SWT likes bravery, even if it's shown by killing a snake. (this and more on bravery is [here](http://www.livingislam.org/n/hv_e.html)).

So, it's pretty clear that if someone dies from trying something risky won't be considered as suicide.